# How to get data from different divs which have same class and store it in .csv file

Tags: java, csv, jsoup

I have multiple divs in a webpage URL that I have to parse which have the same class name but different names,values and ids.
for instance.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control is-datepick" name="fromDate" value="01/07/2017" type="text" id="popupDatepicker" placeholder="Date">
  <input class="form-control is-datepick" name="toDate" value="26/09/2017" type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" placeholder="Date">
</div>
```

Now! I want to get the data between the dates provided above. For that I used jsoup library.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(tempUrl).timeout(10000).data("fromDate", "01/07/2017")
                .data("toDate", dateFormat.format(date))
                .data("type", "text")
                .data("search", "search")
                .timeout(100000).get();
```

and I used getElementsByClass() to get the data. But, unfortunately its not working.

```
File fold = new File("D:\\KSE\\TMP\\NCCPL-YEARLY.csv");
fold.delete();
File fnew = new File("D:\\KSE\\TMP\\NCCPL-YEARLY.csv");
for (Element table : doc.getElementsByClass("fromDate"))
{

    for (Element trElement : table.getElementsByTag("tr")) {

        trElement2 = trElement.getElementsByTag("tr");
        tdElements = trElement.getElementsByTag("td");
        FileWriter sb = new FileWriter(fnew, true);

        //if (table.hasClass("marketData")) { //&&(tdElements.hasClass("tableHead")&&tdElements.hasClass("tableSubHead"))
        for (Iterator<Element> it = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            if (it.hasNext()&& i>0) {
                ///sb.append(" | ");
                sb.append(" \r\n ");
            }

            for (Iterator<Element> it2 = tdElements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Element tdElement2 = it.next();
                final String content = tdElement2.text().replace(",", "");
                if (it2.hasNext()) {

                    sb.append(formatData(content));
                    sb.append("   |   ");

                }

            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            sb.flush();
            sb.close();
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(sampleList.add(tdElements));


    }

}
}
```

The program has successfully compiled and gives no error. Currently, I am facing two problems.
1)It is not creating any csv file.
2)I did some changes in code before that it was creating the file but not reading the dates I have mentioned above. It retrieve the data on the default date which is fromDate= 27/09/2017 toDate= 27/09/2017.
Can anyone please tell me where I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `getElementsByClass("fromDate")` , whereas neither of the `<input>'s` in the html snippet have class `fromDate`. One has `name='fromDate'`, so to retrieve that you need to call `doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "fromDate")`. More on that on https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with `fromDate` class, `<tr>`, nor `<td>` in your HTML code, but you try to iterate on them in your code. Since the selected element list is empty, the `for` loops can't start, so nothing is written to the output CSV files.

If you want to select elements like `<input name="fromDate" ...>`, you can use the [attribute selector](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
Elements inputs = doc.select("input[name=fromDate]");
```

And you can get the value of that `<input>` with the [`attr(String)` method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attr-java.lang.String-):

```
String value = inputs.get(0).attr("value");
```